# compress base64 image meteor client side

Tags: javascript, image, meteor, base64, compression

I am capturing images via cordova camera plugin (in string base64). The image size comes out to be around 500KB (i have set the quality to 30).
But I need to further reduce the image size without changing its quality. Image of 100Kb should do well.

Basically I want to compress the base64 string image to a smaller desired size. Any javascript directory should also work.

I tried using lzma, lz-string.js but neither worked.

Any insights?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a general purpose compression algorithm (such as LZMA) on already compressed data (such as PNG or JPEG) won't have any difference unless you have considerable redundancy. According to [Cordova documentation about camera plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/), your best bet either reduce `quality` or set `targetHeight` and `targetWidth` to resize image. I believe, you want to consider to use `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` instead of `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` for `destinationType` option.

Comment: I have set the quality to 30, and going further down detoriates image quality. I tried using FILE-URI but I wasn't able to figure out how to store and display images (I don't want the users to be able to download the images)

Comment: @NamanGupta Did you tried to set `targetWidth` and `targetHeight`? If it won't work for you (i.e. you want to keep original dimensions), I think you don't have any option other than `FILE_URI`.

Comment: Okay. Will look into FILE_URI then. Thanks!